# Getting error Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, html

I am getting the error
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/happen/public_html/123.com/index.php:1) in /home/happen/public_html/123.com/include/fg_membersite_1.php on line 113"

```
<?php
require_once("./include/membersite_config_1.php");
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{if($fgmembersite1->RegisterUser())
{$fgmembersite1->RedirectToURL("thank-you-uploaded.html");}}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

How can I resolve this? I tried so many things.....no effect.....Please try to help....

Comment: Have you tried googling what "headers already sent" means?

Comment: Check any Whitespace before <?php or after ?> php tags

Comment: i checked that....there is no white space